# syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end ruby

Tags: ruby

A simple CLI program. I am taking the input from user about ingredients until user enters nothing. Joining all the ingredients by a comma and returning it.

```
ingredient = []
int i = 0
ingredients = ""

puts "Enter ingredients :"

loop do
 puts "Ingredient #{i+1}"
 ingredient[i] = gets.chomp
 break if ingredient[i] = ""
 i++
end

ingredients = ingredient.join ","

puts ingredients
```

I don't know what's wrong with this but I keep getting the error "syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end". Please help.

Comment: `int i = 0` -  do you mean `i = 0`?

Comment: C habits die hard, don't they?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ingredient = []
i = 0 # No int
ingredients = ""

puts "Enter ingredients :"

loop do
  puts "Ingredient #{i+1}"
  ingredient[i] = gets.chomp
  break if ingredient[i] == "" # == in comparison 
  i+=1 # NOT i++
end

ingredients = ingredient.join ","
puts ingredients
```

Comment: I tried this. It's not showing any error now, but it's not properly running the loop.As soon as it takes the first input, it exits the loop. Any suggestions?

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Only problem was, when you enter the last ingredient as blank and it exits the loop, it still puts a comma at the end of the string, and I didn't want that. So I entered `ingredient.reject!(&:empty?)` just before join statement to remove empty elements in the array.